# Running android unit test with Buck

Tags: android, unit-testing, junit, buck

I have configured a project with Buck, I can build without problems, for example using:

```
buck install
```

But I can not run the unit tests, Buck [documentation](https://buckbuild.com/command/test.html) says:

```
buck test --all
```

But this returns:

> No tests to run

This is my project:

```
Project Root
  |- app/
    |- src/
      |- main   
        |- java (java source)
        |- res  (androi res)
      |- test   
        |- java (unit tests)
  |- moduleA
    |- src/
      |- main   
        |- java (java source)
        |- res  (androi res)
      |- test   
        |- java (unit tests)
  |- moduleB
    |- src/
      |- main   
        |- java (java source)
        |- res  (androi res)
      |- test   
        |- java (unit tests)
```

I suppose that I must configure something more...

Any idea?

Comment: What do your BUCK files look like? In particular, did you define any test rules in your BUCK files? For an Android project, you will most likely want to use [java_test](https://buckbuild.com/rule/java_test.html) or maybe [android_instrumentation_test](https://buckbuild.com/rule/android_instrumentation_test.html).